# Intermittent connection errors

Tags: mysql

I am experiencing occasional connection errors from my webserver to one of my databases.

The code attempts to connect. If it fails, it sleeps for 1 second, then retries, then (if it still fails) sleeps for 2 seconds more and retries, then gives up if it didn't work

The error messages that come back are:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.0.210' (4) 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.0.210' (113)
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.0.210' (113)
```

4 = interrupted system call

113 = no route to host

I am trying to work out what sequence of events might cause this to happen so I can try and resolve the issue. My hunch is that it's a network issue, but the two machines are both VPSs in the same cloud, so I am not sure how this could be the case!

Comment: @Ben Holness If it is relatively frequent, you can check it is the network by having a watchdog on localhost(mysql node) connecting once per seccond using a unix socket. Just some random idea to confirm/discard network problems.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using ubuntu, give a try by using the below steps:

```
    run the command nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
    comment bind-address = 127.0.0.1 using the # symbol
    restart your mysql server once.
```

Comment: that wouldn't create *intermittent* connection errors.

Comment: This would really mess things up seeing as the server binds to a 10.0.0 address ... besides, as @jynus says, this wouldn't create the intermittent errors I'm having - it works just fine 99% of the time.